# What implications does 'tener' carry in expressions of state-of-being?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, etimología, modismos, significado

### Context

In Spanish 1 & 2 I was taught expressions such as *tener [frío](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=fr%C3%ADo)*, and *tener [sueño](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=sue%C3%B1o)*. Some of the English phrases ***to be + adj*** are ***tener + noun*** in Spanish.

I have noticed that many English adjectives ending in *-y* that have a nominal complement are used in such expressions: *thirsty* (thirst), *hungry* (hunger), *sleepy* (sleep), *happy* (happiness), *gloomy*/glum (gloom, sadness) -- with the exception of *hurriedness* (hurry).

I understand that Latin does not have a verb meaning "to have," so I assume that *tener* carries with it a meaning slightly different than what an English speaker would expect.

---

### Question

**What extra meaning, if any, does the construction carry by using *tener* instead of *ser* or *estar*?** (N.B. I know the uses of *ser* and *estar* and when to use each.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a question about something that Spanish speakers take for granted without stopping to think why that is so.

The verb *tener* comes from Latin *tenere*. If you search that verb in a Latin dictionary, the meaning is just *sostener, mantener, agarrar* (to hold). In fact, if you search the verb [*tener*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZT8sFSB) in the DRAE, the first meaning is precisely that:

> 1. tr. Asir o mantener asido algo.

But the verb has 24 other meanings, and the extra meaning you are seeking is number 12:

> 12. tr. experimentar. *Tener vergüenza, miedo, hambre, calor, nervios.*

The definition of *[experimentar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HIutMRm)* includes the following meaning:

> 2. tr. Notar, echar de ver en uno mismo una cosa, una impresión, un sentimiento, etc.

So basically, if you say *tengo hambre*, what you are really saying in Spanish is something like *estoy experimentando la sensación de hambre*.

Now another question could be when the verb *tener* got this extra meaning. It seems something relatively recent. [Searching the expression in Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tengo%20fr%C3%ADo%2C%20tengo%20hambre&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctengo%20fr%C3%ADo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctengo%20hambre%3B%2Cc0) the matches start in the XVIII or XIX centuries, depending on the search term. Just think that we can also use other expressions such as *estoy hambriento* or *estoy gélido* that indeed use the verb *estar*. But I'm sure there are people here that can answer that part much better than me.

By the way, in English you can also use the verb *to have* to indicate that you are experiencing a feeling: *please, have fun!*

Comment: Tener is experimentar. Experimentar means to experience something. Therefore, the extra meaning from tener is basically to experience hunger, cold, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the verb 'tener' does have a slightly different meaning than 'to have' in English. Well, the meaning is the same but it is a much more diverse word in Spanish and can be used to express more things, often where in English we would simply use 'to be + adjective'.

The thing about 'tener' is that it not only displays the meaning of 'to have' but has a much wider range of uses and meanings than the word 'have' in English.

**tener frío** (to be cold) Olvidé mi suéter y ahora tengo mucho frío. (I forgot my sweater, and now I am very cold.)

**tener calor** (to be hot) Los chicos están sudando. Seguramente tienen mucho calor. (The boys are sweating. They must be very hot.)

**tener hambre** (to be hungry) ¡Mira los perritos! Tienen hambre. No han comido nada. (Look at the dogs! They are hungry. They have not eaten anything.)

**tener sed** (to be thirsty) No he tomado agua todo el día. ¡Tengo mucha sed! (I haven’t drank water the whole day. I’m so thirsty!)

This post has a lot of examples of common expressions where the verb 'tener' is used: https://www.clozemaster.com/blog/spanish-tener-expressions/

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Welcome to the Spanish Language forum. Please notice that you are not really answering the question; the original poster (OP) says that he knows when to use each construction, but wants to know if they carry different meanings.

Comment: Undeleting so you can perform the same good changes you did to the rest of your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Let me address one more thing, you've got the clue in your first paragraph.

English uses **to be + Adj** whereas Spanish uses **tener + noun**.

The issue would be different if it were "tener + Adj". Then you should definitely wonder why the verb changes.

However, you actually can use **to be + Adj** in Spanish. The thing is that it is not common.

You can say

> I am thirsty = Estoy sediento
>
> I am hungry = Estoy hambriento
>
> I am sleepy = Estoy somnoliento

and many others.

However, the other structure is just more common. HEre, tener means to have, in the sense of "to suffer".

> Tengo sed = I suffer from thirst
>
> Tengo hambre = I suffer from hunger
>
> Tengo sueño = I suffer from sleepyness

And so on